# Combining multiple columns/variables into a single column

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have the following problem (I guess there is an easy answer to it, but I can't figure it out...).

I want to combine multiple columns into a single column. I have 3 variables and there are cases that answered variable 1, cases that answered variable 2, cases that answered variable 3 and cases that answered none of the variables.

Now, I want to combine them all in a single variable, that looks like column `vx`:

```
Ideal result: 

  v1 v2 v3 vx
1   1 NA NA  1
2   3 NA NA  3
3   6 NA NA  6
4  NA  5 NA  5
5  NA  1 NA  1
6  NA  3 NA  3
7  NA NA  4  4
8  NA NA  2  2
9  NA NA  1  1
10 NA NA NA NA
```

```
v1 <- c(1, 3, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
v2 <- c(NA, NA, NA, 5, 1, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA)
v3 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 2, 1, NA)

df <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3)
```

I tried it with `df$vx <- paste(df$v1, df$v2, df$v3)` but then I get the following result:

```
My result: 

 v1 v2 v3       vx
1   1 NA NA  1 NA NA
2   3 NA NA  3 NA NA
3   6 NA NA  6 NA NA
4  NA  5 NA  NA 5 NA
5  NA  1 NA  NA 1 NA
6  NA  3 NA  NA 3 NA
7  NA NA  4  NA NA 4
8  NA NA  2  NA NA 2
9  NA NA  1  NA NA 1
10 NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Can someone tell me how I get a result like the one above (ideal result) without the `NAs` (except if there are only `NAs` then I would like to have only one `NA` in column `vx`)

I hope I made clear what my issue is.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what `dplyr::coalesce` was made for:

```r
library(dplyr)
df$v4 <- coalesce(!!!df)

#Also works:
df %>% 
  mutate(v4 = coalesce(v1, v2, v3))
```

output

```r
   v1 v2 v3 v4
1   1 NA NA  1
2   3 NA NA  3
3   6 NA NA  6
4  NA  5 NA  5
5  NA  1 NA  1
6  NA  3 NA  3
7  NA NA  4  4
8  NA NA  2  2
9  NA NA  1  1
10 NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `apply()`

```
# Your data.
v1 = c(1, 3, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
v2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 5, 1, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA)
v3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 2, 1, NA)

df = data.frame(v1, v2, v3)
df

# Solution: writing a function to be passed in apply().
useful.function = function(x)
{
  # The input "x" is a row of a dataframe.
  
  # If all the values are NA, return NA.
  if(sum(!is.na(x)) == 0)
    return(NA)
  
  # Otherwise, return the non-NA value.
  return(x[!is.na(x)])
}

df$vx = apply(df, MARGIN = 1, useful.function)
df
```

Clearly, other solutions may be faster and require less coding (as those relying on the `dplyr` package, posted by @Maël). However, I really suggest you to get confident in using `apply()` and the other functions from the same family (see `lapply()` and `sapply()`), as they are really flexible (and sometimes you may not be aware of the existence of a certain function or package).

Comment: Thank you, I went for the easy sollution with coalesce but nevertheless thanks for the advice! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `max.col` in base R -

```
df$vx <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(!is.na(df)))]
df

#   v1 v2 v3 vx
#1   1 NA NA  1
#2   3 NA NA  3
#3   6 NA NA  6
#4  NA  5 NA  5
#5  NA  1 NA  1
#6  NA  3 NA  3
#7  NA NA  4  4
#8  NA NA  2  2
#9  NA NA  1  1
#10 NA NA NA NA
```

`max.col` returns the index of max value in each row. With `!is.na(df)` we'll get the index of `TRUE` value in each row because `TRUE > FALSE`. We create a matrix with `cbind` to extract the max value from each row.